# Header function not redirecting?

Tags: php

Please help
I have this php code(below) that creates and inserts a user into database after validating user inputs. I am storing the users input in an array. The problem is
It creates the user and inserts it to database but it does not redirect.
Here's the code

```
$validation = new Validate();

if($validation->passed()) {
 //if success, insert(create) user
 try {
  $user = new User();
  $salt = Crypt::salt(32); 
  $user->insert(array(
    'username' => Accept::get('username'),
    'password' => Crypt::make(Accept::get('password'), $salt),
    'salt'  => $salt,
    'name' =>  Accept::get('name')
    ));
  //After creation, redirect user
 header('Location : index.php');
 exit();

 } catch(Exception $e) { //otherwise display errors

    die("ERROR : CAN NOT REGISTER USER ".$e->getMessage());
 }
```

This Code Creates user in database, but it does not redirect. I really don't understand why.

Comment: Do you get any errors (and is error_reporting turned on?) or is it simply just not redirecting?

Comment: I turned on error reporting. I don't get messages at all. It even inserts to database. Just not redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure that you do not `echo/output` anything before the `header() function` not even blank space

2) write these at top of page to see errors

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

3) try `ob_start();` or `ob_flush();`

```
ob_start();// at top of page
    $validation = new Validate();

    if($validation->passed()) {
     //if success, insert(create) user
     try {
      $user = new User();
      $salt = Crypt::salt(32); 
      $user->insert(array(
        'username' => Accept::get('username'),
        'password' => Crypt::make(Accept::get('password'), $salt),
        'salt'  => $salt,
        'name' =>  Accept::get('name')
        ));
      //After creation, redirect user
     header('Location : index.php');
     exit();
    ob_flush();

     } catch(Exception $e) { //otherwise display errors

        die("ERROR : CAN NOT REGISTER USER ".$e->getMessage());
     }
```